# Android crash : /data/user/0/[my app]/cache/WebView is not a directory

Tags: android, admob, crashlytics

Hi I'm in a bit of bind here.
My app doesn't use webview anywhere, and my most frequent crash in Crashlytics is this error : /data/user/0/[myApp]/cache/WebView is not a directory.

The stack trace is minified despite me not using Proguard to minify/obfuscate so it's probably a lib I'm using.

```
Caused by java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /data/user/0/[myApp]/cache/WebView is not a directory.
       at bHS.<init>(SourceFile:58)
       at akR.a(SourceFile:7)
       at aoN.call(SourceFile:7)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
       at aoR.run(SourceFile:2)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

I'm thinking adMob since it's the only thing that could use a webView or maybe crashlytics itself ?

Has anyone encounter this problem or any lead on how to fix it ?
I tried creating this folder on app startup but it's deleted.

Answer (score 3):

In my case it was that i did not add permissions for internet usage in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/android-webview-dev/wvf1qvSvWiI) on the "android-webview-dev" Google Group by a chromium dev:

> That looks like a real bug, and it would never show up in our crash reporting because that's crashing in crash handling code.

So it looks like the crash is within Chromium's crash reporting code which... doesn't help you much.

Can you reproduce it at all, or have any users told you how it happened? Additionally, is there any additional information available on Crashlytics (e.g. it only happens on certain Android versions / certain devices)?

Comment: It's diversified, all android versions/devices , sometimes I can see in another thread an exception in my code, sometimes not. I harmonized the support lib versions in my app recently and this crash is happening less than before since then so it's all good.